# FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://example.firebaseio.com/") is obsolete in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error when I am trying to run the firebase database in the unity editor.

> FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://example.firebaseio.com/") is obsolete

[image]

Comment: This looks like a warning, not an error .. does the rest basically work? -> you can probably ignore it

Comment: @derHugo Unity crashes after that.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing a similar kind of problem, there is an issue with the latest SDK of firebase 6.16.0.
A detailed solution to this problem can be found on this link [on Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/807).

Solution:
Created the folder with the same name as your app bundle ID on windows AppData\Local directory.
For example, on my PC the path was C:\Users\home\AppData\Local, I then created the folder by name "com.liftcad.cad" which is my bundle ID.
This solution helped me a lot. Huge thanks to user @snorrsi from Github.

Comment: I totally missed this before or I would've chimed in! That call (SetEditorDatabaseUrl) has been deprecated and should no longer be in the SDK. For the crash, that has been fixed in the 6.16.1 SDK (and Firebase is currently on 7.0.1)

Comment: @PatrickMartin Thanks for the update. Yes, I can confirm that after the latest update, no such issues were found. I know this is off topic, but any plans to support UNITY WEBGL builds with full SDK features in near future? Right now we have to transfer data as jslib and use javascript SDK.

Comment: I can't comment on future direction, but you can always file a feature request here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features