# FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl Error

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm trying to add my firebase realtime database url to `unity` using this code:-

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://veritabani-linkiniz.firebaseio.com/");
```

But the `unity` doesn't recognize this code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440100/firebaseapp-defaultinstance-seteditordatabaseurlhttps-example-firebaseio-com

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the reference documentation for the `FirebaseDatabase` class, there doesn't seem to be a `SetEditorDatabaseUrl` method, so that would explain the error message.

You might be looking for:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://veritabani-linkiniz.firebaseio.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

`getInstance` should be

```
FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("url-here");
```